# Postgresql data to SSD drive

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have postgresql installed on my desktop computer and just added a 512 GB SSD drive. I thought I would migrate the data to the SSD, so I followed these instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Now when I try to log onto postgres with psql I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here are the results of sudo systemctl status postgresql

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2016-11-16 13:25:32 MST; 35min ago
Process: 995 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 995 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Nov 16 13:25:32 arscoftc1rrgaf6 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 16 13:25:32 arscoftc1rrgaf6 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

And here are the results of pg_lsclusters

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Datadirectory      Log file
9.6 main    5432 down   postgres /media/rowangaffney/88e94ba6-a713-4d87-a066-0ca08f8fd856/DB_DATA/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Also here are the results of systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service

```
● postgresql@9.6-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-11-17 08:24:10 MST; 8s ago
Process: 11618 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And ps auxw | grep postgres

```
rowanga+ 11942  0.0  0.0  14224   944 pts/4    S+   08:36   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

When I run;
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres -d 1 -D /mnt/ssd/postgresql/9.6/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf

The startup process gets stuck in a autovacuum loop of my three databases:

```
2016-11-17 15:07:21 MST [7680-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "cper"
2016-11-17 15:07:41 MST [7694-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "blm_seeds2"
2016-11-17 15:08:01 MST [7700-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "postgres"
2016-11-17 15:08:21 MST [7701-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "cper"
2016-11-17 15:08:41 MST [7702-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "blm_seeds2"
2016-11-17 15:09:01 MST [7708-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "postgres"
2016-11-17 15:09:21 MST [7712-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "cper"
2016-11-17 15:09:41 MST [7713-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "blm_seeds2"
2016-11-17 15:10:01 MST [7716-1] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "postgres"
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Well 1) **is** postgres running `ps auxw | grep postgres` 2) can you **connect** to it `psql -h localhost postgres` ?

Comment: I can't connect with psql. See above for the results of ps auxw | grep postgres.

Comment: Try to start it manually `postgres -D /mnt/your_data_directory` . if that works: change the /etc/init.d/postgres script (or the /etc/..../conf file in your link) to use the correct data - directory instead of the old one.

Comment: I changed the /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgres.conf file to have the new data directory. When I run postgres -D /mnt/your_data_directory I get: No command 'postgres' found

Comment: BTW I am running postgresql 9.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `No command 'postgres' found` := the executable is not in your path. Was the executable (postgres, or postmaster) also on your old directory ? (you can see how it was called by looking into the /etc/init.d/ directory)

Comment: hmm. I see postgresql in the /etc/init.d/ directory. I have never called postgres directly I usually just connect to the db with psql. Do I need to add an environmental varaible (ie export PGDATA=/mnt/your_data_directory) in the /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/environment file???

Comment: Normally startup of the DBMS engine is done at startup time (when switching to user mode) that is the reason why it is under /etc/inet.d/ . There might be small differences between linux destributions ( For example: I have never seen a directory /etc/postgres/9.5/main ; which presumably contains the settings in some other destribution) The PG data-directory is often (hard)coded somewhere in /etc/init.d/postgresql.

Comment: Hmm I don't see a data directory variable/call in the postgresql file under init.d

Comment: Well, maybe the file with environment variables / settings is sourced. I don't know your distribution, and I cannot tell from here what you changed in your installation.

Comment: I figured out what is wrong - see revised comment at end of post. If anyone knows of a solution please let me know - thanks.